# How to retrieve data from previous record from maximum in ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with `Client Name`, `Contract_id`, and four columns `Total1`, `Total2`, `Total3` and `Total4`.

I need to retrieve in one row for each client the values of `Total1`, `Total2`, `Total3` and `Total4` from maximum record and previous record.

Have next:

enter image description here

[image]

Need to get like that:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please describe what is the maximum record? Maximum of what?

Comment: I meant the latest. I need to compare latest and previous. If a company has more contracts, need to apply the same rule for all contracts per one Company.

Comment: In my case above, in first row will be data for contract_id 550705 and 552854, next row should be contract_id 552854 and 564015 etc...

Comment: I don't get it. The lastest two contracts per company? But how to tell which are the latest? There is no date in the table. And obviously we cannot use the contract ID for that either, because in the result you are showing you dismiss some higher IDs (which I would have assumed to be "later"). And at last you say in the comments you also want a result row for the second and third last contract? But this is different from what you are saying in your request. So, what do you want  exactly? How to determine which row is newer than another? Please update your request with this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the below which comes close to your requirement.[The DB Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e062b34c0bdffa425f3a5e574aee98f3)

```
with data as (select t.*,Row_number() over(partition by c_name order by rownum) row_num from testtt1 t 

    ),data1 as (
    select c_name,LISTAGG((c_id || ',' || t1 ||','|| t2 || ',' || t3 ||',' ||t4), '| ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY row_num)  product_info from data
    where row_num<=2
    group by c_name
    union 
    select 'c_name' c_name,LISTAGG(('c_id' || ',' || 't1' ||','|| 't2' || ',' || 't3' ||',' ||'t4'), '| ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY row_num)  product_info from data
    where row_num<=1
    group by 'c_name'
    )
    select c_name as " ",replace(product_info,',',chr(9)) as " " from data1
    order by decode(c_name,'c_name',c_name) ;
```

The Answer looks like the below

```
        c_name  c_id    t1  t2  t3  t4| c_id    t1  t2  t3  t4
        Company 583002  100 200 300 400| 564015 100 800 500 400
        Ontario 550705  100 200 300 400| 552854 100 800 500 400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LAST_VALUE analytic function with windowing clause looking just current and next row.
I preserved the order of your rows from question by creating **"tblord"** CTE and then do the rest. You can skip this part if there is another way to sort your data. In that case just put your sorting instead of mine ORDER BY ROWNO everywhere it appears.
The final row of a client is excluded as it has the same CONTRACT_ID and NEXT_CONTRACT_ID as well as all the other columns. If you want them too then just remove the outer query and it's WHERE clause.
Regards...

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
          Select 'Ontario Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '550705' "CONTRACT_ID", 5667.9 "TOTAL1", 325.1 "TOTAL2", 677.8 "TOTAL3", 78890.78 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Ontario Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '552854' "CONTRACT_ID", 6779.98 "TOTAL1", 223.5 "TOTAL2", 811.9 "TOTAL3", 10000.01 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Ontario Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '564015' "CONTRACT_ID", 2234 "TOTAL1", 345.9 "TOTAL2", 799.67 "TOTAL3", 1100.09 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Ontario Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '583002' "CONTRACT_ID", 657 "TOTAL1", 245 "TOTAL2", 888 "TOTAL3", 1000 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Company Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '564015' "CONTRACT_ID", 2234 "TOTAL1", 345.9 "TOTAL2", 799.67 "TOTAL3", 1100.09 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Company Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '583002' "CONTRACT_ID", 657 "TOTAL1", 245 "TOTAL2", 888 "TOTAL3", 1000 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Company Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '550705' "CONTRACT_ID", 5667.9 "TOTAL1", 325.1 "TOTAL2", 677.8 "TOTAL3", 78890.78 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Company Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '552854' "CONTRACT_ID", 6779.98 "TOTAL1", 223.5 "TOTAL2", 811.9 "TOTAL3", 10000.01 "TOTAL4" From Dual 
        ),
    tblord AS
        (
            SELECT
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) "ROWNO",
              CLIENT_NAME "CLIENT_NAME",
              CONTRACT_ID "CONTRACT_ID",
              TOTAL1 "TOTAL1",
              TOTAL2 "TOTAL2",
              TOTAL3 "TOTAL3",
              TOTAL4 "TOTAL4"
            FROM
              tbl
        )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CLIENT_NAME, CONTRACT_ID, TOTAL1, TOTAL2, TOTAL3, TOTAL4,
            LAST_VALUE(CONTRACT_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_CONTRACT_ID",
            LAST_VALUE(TOTAL1) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_TOTAL1",
            LAST_VALUE(TOTAL2) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_TOTAL2",
            LAST_VALUE(TOTAL3) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_TOTAL3",
            LAST_VALUE(TOTAL4) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_TOTAL4"
        FROM  
            tblord
        ORDER BY
            ROWNO
    )
WHERE 
    CONTRACT_ID <> NEXT_CONTRACT_ID
--
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  CLIENT_NAME  CONTRACT_ID     TOTAL1     TOTAL2     TOTAL3     TOTAL4 NEXT_CONTRACT_ID NEXT_TOTAL1 NEXT_TOTAL2 NEXT_TOTAL3 NEXT_TOTAL4
--  ------------ ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
--  Ontario Inc. 550705          5667.9      325.1      677.8   78890.78 552854               6779.98       223.5       811.9    10000.01 
--  Ontario Inc. 552854         6779.98      223.5      811.9   10000.01 564015                  2234       345.9      799.67     1100.09 
--  Ontario Inc. 564015            2234      345.9     799.67    1100.09 583002                   657         245         888        1000 
--  Company Inc. 564015            2234      345.9     799.67    1100.09 583002                   657         245         888        1000 
--  Company Inc. 583002             657        245        888       1000 550705                5667.9       325.1       677.8    78890.78 
--  Company Inc. 550705          5667.9      325.1      677.8   78890.78 552854               6779.98       223.5       811.9    10000.01
```

**ADDITION**
In case you should show last rows of clients contracts, the one without next, it would be odd to populate "next" fields with the same values as in the left side - then I suggest you to change the main outer select like below and to remove WHERE clause of that main outer select. It will in the  same time solve the problem where there is a client with just one contract (I added one in the WITH tbl AS)

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
          Select 'Another Co. Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '550999' "CONTRACT_ID", 5000.9 "TOTAL1", 300.1 "TOTAL2", 600.8 "TOTAL3", 78000.78 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Ontario Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '550705' "CONTRACT_ID", 5667.9 "TOTAL1", 325.1 "TOTAL2", 677.8 "TOTAL3", 78890.78 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Ontario Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '552854' "CONTRACT_ID", 6779.98 "TOTAL1", 223.5 "TOTAL2", 811.9 "TOTAL3", 10000.01 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Ontario Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '564015' "CONTRACT_ID", 2234 "TOTAL1", 345.9 "TOTAL2", 799.67 "TOTAL3", 1100.09 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Ontario Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '583002' "CONTRACT_ID", 657 "TOTAL1", 245 "TOTAL2", 888 "TOTAL3", 1000 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Company Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '564015' "CONTRACT_ID", 2234 "TOTAL1", 345.9 "TOTAL2", 799.67 "TOTAL3", 1100.09 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Company Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '583002' "CONTRACT_ID", 657 "TOTAL1", 245 "TOTAL2", 888 "TOTAL3", 1000 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Company Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '550705' "CONTRACT_ID", 5667.9 "TOTAL1", 325.1 "TOTAL2", 677.8 "TOTAL3", 78890.78 "TOTAL4" From Dual UNION ALL
          Select 'Company Inc.' "CLIENT_NAME", '552854' "CONTRACT_ID", 6779.98 "TOTAL1", 223.5 "TOTAL2", 811.9 "TOTAL3", 10000.01 "TOTAL4" From Dual 
        ),
    tblord AS
        (
            SELECT
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) "ROWNO",
              CLIENT_NAME "CLIENT_NAME",
              CONTRACT_ID "CONTRACT_ID",
              TOTAL1 "TOTAL1",
              TOTAL2 "TOTAL2",
              TOTAL3 "TOTAL3",
              TOTAL4 "TOTAL4"
            FROM
              tbl
        )
SELECT
    CLIENT_NAME, CONTRACT_ID, TOTAL1, TOTAL2, TOTAL3, TOTAL4,
    CASE WHEN CONTRACT_ID = NEXT_CONTRACT_ID THEN Null ELSE NEXT_CONTRACT_ID END "NEXT_CONTRACT_ID",
    CASE WHEN CONTRACT_ID = NEXT_CONTRACT_ID THEN Null ELSE NEXT_TOTAL1 END "NEXT_TOTAL1",
    CASE WHEN CONTRACT_ID = NEXT_CONTRACT_ID THEN Null ELSE NEXT_TOTAL2 END "NEXT_TOTAL2",
    CASE WHEN CONTRACT_ID = NEXT_CONTRACT_ID THEN Null ELSE NEXT_TOTAL3 END "NEXT_TOTAL3",
    CASE WHEN CONTRACT_ID = NEXT_CONTRACT_ID THEN Null ELSE NEXT_TOTAL4 END "NEXT_TOTAL4"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CLIENT_NAME, CONTRACT_ID, TOTAL1, TOTAL2, TOTAL3, TOTAL4,
            LAST_VALUE(CONTRACT_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_CONTRACT_ID",
            LAST_VALUE(TOTAL1) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_TOTAL1",
            LAST_VALUE(TOTAL2) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_TOTAL2",
            LAST_VALUE(TOTAL3) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_TOTAL3",
            LAST_VALUE(TOTAL4) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_NAME ORDER BY ROWNO ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) "NEXT_TOTAL4"
        FROM  
            tblord
        ORDER BY
            ROWNO
    )
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  CLIENT_NAME      CONTRACT_ID     TOTAL1     TOTAL2     TOTAL3     TOTAL4 NEXT_CONTRACT_ID NEXT_TOTAL1 NEXT_TOTAL2 NEXT_TOTAL3 NEXT_TOTAL4
--  ---------------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
--  Another Co. Inc. 550999          5000.9      300.1      600.8   78000.78                                                                  
--  Ontario Inc.     550705          5667.9      325.1      677.8   78890.78 552854               6779.98       223.5       811.9    10000.01 
--  Ontario Inc.     552854         6779.98      223.5      811.9   10000.01 564015                  2234       345.9      799.67     1100.09 
--  Ontario Inc.     564015            2234      345.9     799.67    1100.09 583002                   657         245         888        1000 
--  Ontario Inc.     583002             657        245        888       1000                                                                  
--  Company Inc.     564015            2234      345.9     799.67    1100.09 583002                   657         245         888        1000 
--  Company Inc.     583002             657        245        888       1000 550705                5667.9       325.1       677.8    78890.78 
--  Company Inc.     550705          5667.9      325.1      677.8   78890.78 552854               6779.98       223.5       811.9    10000.01 
--  Company Inc.     552854         6779.98      223.5      811.9   10000.01
```

It is also possible to write main sql in a way that it selects rows with clients having just one contract and exclude the final (last) row of those having more than one contract and whose last contract data are already shown in the "next" (right) side of the resulting dataset. Hopee this will be usefull. Regards...

Comment: Glad to know. You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the accept button. Regards.

Comment: This script works perfect if a Client has more contracts, what if there is just one contract per client? It should be included in the list also. Thanks

Comment: I mentioned it in the answer too. " If you want them too then just remove the outer query and it's WHERE clause." That way it will be there. If there is just one that is the last one in the same time.

Comment: @user276336 Just posted an Addition with a possibilities of this answer, as well as a suggestion for a bit different resulting dataset. Regards...

Comment: @user276336 Btw. Oracle analytic functions used with windowing clause (ROWS | RANGE Between .... And ...)  could be very usefull and effective in such multi row conceptual questions. More about it at ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174 )

Comment: Thanks, its exactly what I need. Perfect results for both cases. Thx

Comment: You are welcome. You can acceot it then.